# Syntax error in API JSON File

Tags: javascript, json, jsonp

I'm sending a json request to this url https://data.dublinked.ie/cgi-bin/rtpi/realtimebusinformation?stopid=213471&format=json

In Chrome's developer console I'm get this error from the JSON file I'm accessing:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Am I doing something wrong or is the json code wrong?

How can I bypass this?

```
function go () {
  send("https://data.dublinked.ie/cgi-bin/rtpi/realtimebusinformation?      stopid=213471&format=json&callback=processData");

  }


 function send(url) {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.setAttribute('src', url );

  var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
  head.appendChild(script);
}


 function processData (data) {
  var dueTimes = document.getElementsByTagName('results')[0];
  var result = document.getElementsByTagName('result');
  var time = document.getElementsByTagName('duetime');

  var one = dueTimes.result[0].time;
  var two = dueTimes.result[1].time;

  document.getElementById("times").innerHTML = "Due: " + one + "Second: " + two;
}


window.onload = go;
```

Comment: How are you parsing the JSON after you receive it? Show us the code you're using for connecting to the API.

Comment: Some source code would be awesome. Do you have control over the web API output? Sometimes the server-side library (Jackson, GSON, et. al.) Can have issues, but it's unlikely. Directly parsing the response with JSON.parse or letting $.ajax do it for you by specifying the dataType parameter as text/JSON should all do the trick...

Comment: @MikeC updated question

Comment: @BlakeNeal added source code to question, first time trying this

Comment: @CianW It doesn't look like that API supports JSONP. Just load it in with a standard AJAX call then parse the response with `JSON.parse`.

Comment: @MikeC thanks I will try that. Do you mind telling me how you found at that it doesn't support jsonp...

Comment: @CianW Because none of their documentation says they do. It only specifies JSON.